# Angular Material Sidenav rendered but not showing

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material, angular8

Currently I am building my own blog with angular 8 and angular material 8.

I have been trying to get my sidenav to work but it is not cooperating. Angular Material documentation says to wrap  with . Ι have done this but whenever I toggle it, it is not showing

I have tried the following, where I have a toolbar for the desktop-tablet and a sidenav for the mobile, as I am going for a responsive website

```
<div>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="fixed-header d-flex">
        <mat-toolbar-row>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" fxHide.gt-sm>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="!sidenav.opened">menu</mat-icon>
                <mat-icon *ngIf="sidenav.opened">clear</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <div [routerLink]="'/'">
                <img src="assets/logo.svg" alt="img" width="40" height="30" align="top">
                <button mat-button disableRipple class="btn btn-outline-none">
                    <span class="font-xl">title</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <span class="menu-space"></span>
            <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md>
                <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/menu1']" mat-button>
                    <span [translate]="'Menu1'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
                <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/menu2']" mat-button>
                    <span [translate]="'Menu2'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
                <a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/menu3']" mat-button>
                    <span [translate]="'Menu3'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
                <a routerLink="active" [routerLink]="['/menu4']" mat-button>
                    <span [translate]="'menu4'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container class="flex-grow-1">
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" role="navigation" [fixedTopGap]="52">
            <mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/menu1']">
                    <span [translate]="'Menu1'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
                <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/menu2']">
                    <span [translate]="'Menu2'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
                <a mat-list-item routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/menu3']">
                    <span [translate]="'Menu3'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
                <a mat-list-item routerLink="active" [routerLink]="['/menu4']">
                    <span [translate]="'Menu4'" class="font-lg"></span>
                </a>
            </mat-nav-list>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Any warnings or errors?

Comment: thank you. My console is clean sadly

Comment: Pulled this slackblitz from the angular material documentation which can help https://stackblitz.com/angular/yoendngnlgg

Comment: Can you provide a demo of your work with [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) for example. It will help us

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmxwhw

Comment: @AyyubKolsawala it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at your stackblitz project:

- You should add `<app-layout></app-layout>` to your `app.component.html` as you are Bootstrapping that and will be the entry to your project
- You should add set the margin of `app-layout` to zero
- You should change the structure of the layout component:

  1. wrap your whole navigation with `<mat-sidenav-container>`
  2. move the `<mat-toolbar>` to the `<mat-sidenav-content>`
  3. add the following classes to `layout.component.scss`

     `mat-sidenav-container,
     mat-sidenav-content,
     mat-sidenav {
     height: 100%;
     }
     mat-sidenav{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     flex: 1 0 auto;
     width: 200px;
     }`
  4. wrap `<router-outlet>` with a `<main>` which specifies the main content of the website.
  5. add a margin-top of around 80px for the main element as you want to have a fixed toolbar
- Now let's fix your routing. If you don't want your '' to navigate to home but to your home component, you should add :

  1. edit your routes in your app-routing.module.ts to match 

     `{
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'home',
     pathMatch: 'full',
     },
     {
     path: '',
     component: LayoutComponent,
     children: [
     {
     path: 'home',
     loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
     }
     ]
     }`

     and
  2. add a home.routing.module.ts with the following

`
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {
        Routes,
        RouterModule
    } from '@angular/router';

```
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule { }
```

`
     3. add the HomeRoutingModule to the imports of your HomeModule

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stackblitz code I managed to get the sidenav work.
Here is my fork of your stackblitz code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5kvkwh

Following steps are needed:

- In `app.component.html` `<app-layout>` need to be used.
- In `app-routing.module.ts` the `home` component should be displayed.
  This is needed to show something in your `<router-outlet>`.
- In `layout-component.html` several steps were needed. One of the main
  points is, that the entire layout should be in a
  `<mat-sidenav-container>` and the main content of your application
  should be in `<mat-sidenav-content>`.
- To have strech the sidenav for the entire page some css modifications
  were needed (`styles.scss`, `app.component.css`,
  `layout.component.scss`).

I recommend you to create separate components for the sidenav, for the header and for the content components. You can find an example to this [in my repo on this url](https://github.com/tenkmilan/angular-dotnet-core-job-portal/tree/master/src/JobPortal/ClientApp).